# SQL Syntax error in CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to Microsoft SQL Server, and I have been doing an exercise in my book. I have been doing pretty well until now... I am trying to create a table from this code, and it says syntax error in create table. I am not sure, I have did research with no luck on a solution. This is what the book says to use, but its not working... Any help will and guidance will be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE  TABLE SALESPERSON
(
  NickName                   Char (35)                 NOT NULL,         
  LastName                   Char (25)                 NOT NULL,
  FirstName                  Char (25)                 NOT NULL,
  HireDate                   DateTime                  NOT NULL
  WageRate                   Numeric                   NOT NULL,
  CommissionRate             Numeric                   NOT NULL,
  Phone                      Char (12)                 NOT NULL,
  Email                      Varchar (100)             NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT SALESPERSON_PK PRIMARY KEY(NickName)
);
```

Comment: Side note: be aware that `CHAR(35)` will mean you **always** get 35 characters - even if you enter only 5 (the rest will be padded up with spaces). This is usually not a very good idea - for any string column of more than 5 character, I'd recommend to always use `VARCHAR(n)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you didn't lose any characters while pasting your script here, I think the syntax error might be due to a missing comma here.

```
 HireDate DateTime NOT NULL, WageRate Numeric
                           ^
```

Comment: Wow, I feel like a fool. I have been staring at this for over 10 minutes and missed something so simple...I am a bit embarrassed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add comma after "  HireDate DateTime NOT NULL ":

try following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SALESPERSON` (
  `NickName` char(35) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` char(25) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` char(25) NOT NULL,
  `HireDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `WageRate` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `CommissionRate` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NickName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: Why did you add backticks around each identifier? And why assume MySQL when the syntax works just fine in other DBMSes (such as SQL Server)?